# Apache drops SSL client cert when using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2, ssl-certificate

I have a PHP script that authenticates users using the client certificate. Apache is configured to require an SSL connection for that script, and it's working fine.

However, I also want requests to the authentication script to be redirected to another file if that file is present. I'm using mod_rewrite for this, and the redirection also works fine if the other file is present, but if it's not, then the auth script is no longer able to see the client certificate.

Example PHP script (ssl_test.php):

```
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY']);
echo "\n";
var_dump($_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']);
?>
</pre>
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <Files ssl_test.php>
        SSLVerifyClient optional
        SSLVerifyDepth 2
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData +OptRenegotiate
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

At this point, if I navigate to ssl_test.php, it displays the client certificate (and `SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY` contains "SUCCESS").

Now I add the following to .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ssl_test.php [NC]
RewriteCond foo.html -F
RewriteRule . foo.html [L]
```

If foo.html is present, then requests to ssl_test.php are redirected, so that part is working. However, if foo.html is *not* present, then ssl_test.php fails to get the client cert - `SSL_CLIENT_CERT` is empty and `SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY` contains "NONE".

This seems to happen whenever ssl_test.php matches the first RewriteCond directive, regardless of whether it contains the actual filename or a regular expression that matches multiple filenames. If I remove the rewrite logic or change the regular expression so it no longer matches ssl_test.php, it starts working again.

What's the problem? I'm probably overlooking something simple, but I've been going over the docs for both mod_rewrite and mod_ssl and can't find anything that would explain this behaviour.

Just to clarify, I don't need the cert to be redirected to foo.html, that's just a static page. I need ssl_test.php to be redirected to foo.html if foo.html exists, and to be able to read the client cert if it doesn't. Right now I can do one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using -F (which involves a subrequest) and not -f (which does not) ? It may be the reason why you are having trouble.

Comment: The reason is that `-f` needs full local paths, but the directory in which the files are contained isn't necessarily always in the webroot, so I can't hard-code the paths, and there doesn't seem to be a way to make `-f` start from the current directory. That's why I use `-F` - it supports relative paths as well. I did check that `-f` with a properly hard-coded path works, though. Do you know why the `-F` subrequest is affecting the client cert in the main request?

Comment: @RemiGacogne I ended up using the `-f` switch and hard-coded paths, so if you want to post that as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.